# jsf primefaces - two p:dataTable pagination questions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using a p:dataTable with pagination like so:

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userBean.users}" 
   paginator="true" rows="20"  
   paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks}" >
```

Two questions:

1) Is there a way to tell it to not show the page numbers when there's only one page?

2) When I click from page 1 to page 2, the whole web page refreshes.  On the PrimeFaces demo the pagination flips pages with an AJAX-style update.  What have I done wrong that the web page is refreshing?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following for question 1:

```
paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
```

From the primefaces javadoc:

**paginatorAlwaysVisible:** Defines if paginator should be hidden when number of rows displayed is less than paginator rowsPerPage option.